# How to display images in Jenkins console output

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am running an automation script through Jenkins where the console gives html image tag containing image but currently the Jenkins console output is not displaying the images in the console output.

Are there any plugins/method in jenkins available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is console and it is absolutely correct to not display images there, cause the only images "available for" consoles are ASCII text decors or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In the console output you can print link to the userContent directory and save image there (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/extending-jenkins/9781785284243/ch04s05.html).

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins console supports only text.

But you can acheive your goal by doing the following things

1) Store the picture (or even videos) jn WORKSPACE directory (usally in the format 
`/user_home/jenkins/jobs/JOB_NAME`) and then archive it as artifact. When an artifact is created, it is shown in jenkins job status and user can download that file. 
Sample Jenkins Pipeline:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: /path/*file*
```

Note: One or more files can be achieved using glob/regexp in file path

2) Allow access to some folders of machine's file system (which might be dangerous) and then create a web app which allows viewing folders/files. Link the file path URL in jenkins console output.